# QTCPSocket - send/read из разных потоков

Tags: многопоточность, qt5, qtcpsocket

Всем доброго времени суток! Ребят, нужна помощь.
Итак, есть класс-клиент через который приложение общается с серваком.

```
class Cls
{
    explicit Cls(QObject*       parent = nullptr,
                 const QString& host   = QString("localhost"),
                 const quint16  port   = 8008);
    ~Cls();

signals:
    void send(const QString&);
    void read();

public slots:
                void sendData(const QString& data);
    Q_INVOKABLE void readData();

private:
    QTcpSocket* mSocket;

    QString     mHost;
    quint16     mPort;

    QMutex      mMutex;
}

void Cls::sendData(const QString& data)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mMutex);
    if(mSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        QByteArray bytes(data.toStdString().c_str());
        mSocket->write(bytes);
        mSocket->flush();
    }
}

void Cls::readData()
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mMutex);
    if (mSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        const quint32 bytes  = mSocket->bytesAvailable();
        QByteArray raw_data(QByteArray::fromRawData(mSocket->readAll(), bytes));

        QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(raw_data);

        ...
    }
}
```

Основные коннекты:

```
connect(mSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &Cls::readData, Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(this,    &Cls::send, this, &Cls::sendData, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Далее, есть 2 функции, которые вызываются из разных потоков, и в этих 2 функциях вызывается Cls:

```
SomeType foo_1(params)
{
...
emit mCls.send("#command_1")
...
}

SomeType foo_2(params)
{
...
emit mCls.send("#command_1")
...
emit mCls.send("#command_2")
...
}
```

Но, т.к. вызывается это в разных потоках, то эти самые потоки можно сказать "рвут" сокет.
Подскажите пожалуйста идеи, как грамотно c архитектурной точки зрения, организовать работу класса Cls, что бы корректно отрабатывали слоты read*/send*, данные корректно отправлялись и соответственно приходили.

Спасибо!

Comment: нужно делать очередь (грубо говоря, `QList<QByteArray>` может быть подходящим решением. Команды "send" будут добавлять в очередь А сам потом уже будет делать отправку. Consumer-Producer. Но обычно, если только отправка с разных потоков, все работает нормально и так.

Comment: Спасибо! С этим разобрались, героически переписав несколько небольших частей.

Comment: Теперь вопрос в другом. Сокет первый раз отправляет данные на сервер, сервер получает и благополучно отправляет ответ. Все гуд. Но.. при второй отправке данных, сокет как будто уходит в loop и соответственно на сервере данных нет, readyRead() не испускается, данные не читаются.

Comment: А кто его знает, что там теперь у Вас написано. Как минимум я бы взял сниффер  (wireshark) и посмотрел, что там бежит и куда

Comment: @KoVadim
Спасибо за вдохновение)
Заснифили, увидели, что подлагивает сервер, подправили сервер, все завелось